# fasta file header lines into column

Tags: python, unix, awk, sed

I have a fasta file that contains sequence headers and their corresponding sequences as so:

```
>ID101_hg19
ATGGGTGTATCGTACCC
>ID102_hg19
AGCTTTAGCGGGGTACA
```

I want to change the header line to be another tab separated column next to the sequence. Here's the desired output:

```
>ID101_hg19    ATGGGTGTATCGTACCC
>ID102_hg19    AGCTTTAGCGGGGTACA
```

Any ideas on how to do this task?

Answer (score 1):

Using Sed, you could do it like:

```
sed 'N;s/\n/\t/' file.txt
```

Using awk, you could do the following:

```
awk '{getline a; printf("%s\t%s", $0, a);}' file.txt
```

Comment: Perfect. Much appreciated. The awk command worked flawlessly.

Comment: After investigating the output, I have noticed that the ID of the next sequence is added to the end of the sequence from the previous entry. Any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: Also, in the `sed` approach, a 't' is printed instead of the tab

Answer (score 1):

A slight correction to SMA's answer...

awk '{getline a; printf("%s\t%s\n", $0, a);}' file.txt

Adds newline

Answer (score 0):

In general, each header line in a FASTA file can be followed by more than one line of data, so one might want to handle such cases.  If the goal is to string together all the contiguous data lines, then the following would do the job:

```
awk '/^>/ {if (prev) {print prev;}; prev=$0 "\t"; next}
     {prev=prev $0;} 
     END {print prev}'
```

If, on the other hand, the header is to be attached to just one line of data, then assuming the $'...' syntax is available, the sed command to use would be:

```
sed $'/^>/ {N;s/\\n/\t/;}'
```